# How Spring's @Async works internally? Why is it safe to use @Async in servlet container (e.g. Tomcat) environment?

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, tomcat, threadpoolexecutor

I'm trying to understand how I can use concurrency in the Tomcat environment.
I saw Spring official tutorials where @Async was used with spring-web dependency. So I gues that is is safe.

On the other hand, I've read [JSR 236: Concurrency Utilities for Java EE](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=236) which tells: "java.util.Timer, java.lang.Thread and the thread pool creation APIs from the Java SE concurrency utilities (JSR-166) in the java.util.concurrent package should never be used within managed environments, as it creates threads outside the purview of the container".

Trying to understand how @Async works I've found out that it is handled by [AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/AsyncAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.html) that uses org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor extends java.util.concurrent.Executor.

May you explain why @Async is safe in a container servlet environment or suggest documentation that explains this aspect?

Thank you.

Comment: link only: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#overview-history :)

Comment: ".. it **integrates with carefully selected** individual specifications from the traditional EE umbrella: ...-Concurrency Utilities (JSR 236) ..."

Comment: or let's say: spring is *inside* "the purview of container"! (Java EE is dead, long live Jakarta EE;))